# Error linking Qt based app

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, qt, qt-signals

We're using a really old version of Qt, 1.1, I think.  Circa 2000.  It's for in-house use only, so there's little concern to upgrade at this time.  Program is built on Windows using Visual Studio 2005.  I know very little of Qt, other than what I've been researching over the last couple days.

The (very basic) architecture is:

- main() creates a QApplication instance.
- main() also creates a pointer to a custom subclass of QWidget called Wizard.
- Wizard creates a number of Controller objects, which are subclassed from QThread.

I am trying to implement a new class / thread, launched from main(), the purpose of which is  to monitor a service and signal an action to be carried out in the Controller objects / threads.

My new class / Thread definition:

```
#include "qthread.h"

class ServiceMonitor : public QThread 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
   ServiceMonitor(int p) : port(p) {}
   ~ServiceMonitor() {};

private:
   void run();
   void TerminateProgram();

signals:
   void SomethingBadHappened();

private:
   int port;
};
```

And in my cpp file:

```
void ServiceMonitor::TerminateProgram()
{
   ...
   emit SomethingBadHappened();
   ...
}
```

When I compile the app, I receive a linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall ServiceMonitor::SomethingBadHappened(void)"
 (?SomethingBadHappened@ServiceMonitor@@IAEXXZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall ServiceMonitor::TerminateProgram(void)"
 (?TerminateProgram@ServiceMonitor@@AAEXXZ) ServiceMonitor.obj
```

I notice that all of our other objects (which have signals) are not derived from Qthread, so I have no examples to follow.  The rest (which do use signals) are derived from QWidget or QObject).  I notice those use the moc.exe in a custom compile step to generate an output file which is included in the project.  I did try to run moc on the header containing the class above and including the output file, where I received:

```
Error   1   error C2039: 'className' : is not a member of 'QThread'
Error   2   error C3861: 'badSuperclassWarning': identifier not found
Error   3   error C2039: 'staticMetaObject' : is not a member of 'QThread'
Error   4   error C3861: 'activate_signal': identifier not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Tried RA's proposal, worked a treat (Once I remembered to include qobject.h).  Thanks!

New definition:

```
#include "qthread.h"
#include "qobject.h"

class ServiceMonitor : public QObject, public QThread
...
```

Comment: You can only define signals, use the `Q_OBJECT` macro and run moc.exe on classes that inherit from `QObject`.  The `QThread` class did not inherit from `QObject` prior to Qt 4.0, which is why you're getting errors.  You can try to use multiple inheritance (i.e., `class ServiceMonitor : public QObject, public QThread` -- note that `QObject` must be first).

Comment: Can you post your updated code?  The errors make it seem like you're not including `qobject.h`.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Repost your comment as an answer and I shall accept.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For versions of Qt prior to Qt 4.0, the `QThread` class did not inherit from `QObject`.  As such, if you want to create a class derived from `QThread` that has signals, you must inherit from both `QObject` and `QThread`:

```
#include "qobject.h"
#include "qthread.h"

class ServiceMonitor : public QObject, public QThread 
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // Rest of class
};
```

Note that `QObject` must be listed as the first class derived from.

Also remember to run `moc` on the class and to compile the generated moc code.

Answer (score 0):

The missing part is the implementation of all the signals, and of the `staticMetaObject` structure that's declared as part of `Q_OBJECT` macro. Those are generated by moc. Moc-ing of the headers would normally be handled by a Qt add-in for Visual Studio. Unfortunately, there are no Qt-5 add-ins for VS 2005.

Your options are, in order of decreasing desirability.

1. Use qmake to generate a VS 2005 project file that invokes moc for you, and includes the necessary files. That would be the best way for you to use Qt.
2. Manually run `moc` on all of the header files that contain the `Q_OBJECT` macro, and add the generated code to your project.
3. Upgrade to at least VS 2008 (not Express), so that you can use the Qt 5 add-in.
4. Try Qt 4, which has an add-in for VS 2005.

Since you can have multiple versions of Qt installed at the same time, you can pursue multiple approaches in parallel. For example, #1 and #4.

Comment: Thanks Kuba.  We are stuck with VS 2005 and Qt 1 for the foreseeable future.  moc is run on the headers and the resulting files included.  It would be nice to update, but not an option at this time.

Comment: @Jon Are you serious? Qt 1? Wow. I missed it in the question! I'd love to port *that* to Qt 5.